# R igraph: Combine Two graph with their edges weights

Tags: r, igraph

I have large graph and i used

```
decom = decompose.graph(gr)
```

to separate weighted connected graphs.
Next, I used below code to combine some of decomposed graphs   :

```
remain_graph = decom[[1]]+decom[[2]]
```

the edges and node are combined correctly but the edge's weight are not transfer to "remain_graph".

```
E(remain_graph)$weigh # answer is NULL
```

While "decom[[1]]" and "decom[[2]]" weights are not empty !!!!!????

```
E(decom[[1]])$weight #answer is 1.22  1  5.666 
E(decom[[2]])$weight #answer is 2.07  5  1.893
```

I test other codes like:

```
g=decom[[1]]
remain_graph= All_graph - E(g)
remain_graph= All_graph - V(g)
```

But this problem is persistent.

Comment: Try using `union` instead: `union(decom[[1]], decom[[2]])`.

Comment: it doesnt work too :(

Comment: Care to provide a reproducible example? However, you have `E(remain_graph)$weigh`, where `weight` is misspelled (missing last `t`). Correct and see if it works.

Comment: I solve my problem by using main data, before build graph: data= subset(data,!(ID %in% IS_LIST)). ID_LIST is ids which have been built graph and in new graph they should be removed. Thanks @nicola for your attention